# Facebook: field expansion in batch requests ->

Tags: facebook, facebook-batch-request

How can I define the requested fields for the 2nd part of my batch request?

Example:

```
[
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "name": "get-friends",
    "relative_url": "me/friends?limit=5",
    "omit_response_on_success": false
  },
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": "?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}"
  }
]
```

This works so far. But now I want to define the requested fields for the 2nd part.

When I add `&fields=address` (`"relative_url": "?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}&fields=address"`) I get a `"Batch parameter must be a JSON array"` exception :-(

Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a "Batch parameter must be a JSON array" exception

That probably just means your query could not be understood, because you invalidated the syntax somehow. `&` has a special meaning in a URL, so you most likely just need to encode it properly.

URL-encode the whole value of the `batch` parameter (so basically your whole JSON string that you got from your object.)

(What function/method to use for that, depends on how you build your request, resp. in what language. PHP has `urlencode`, JavaScript has `encodeURIComponent`, etc.)

Comment: I replaced the `&` with `%26` and it works :-) Now it looks like this `"relative_url": "?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}%26fields=address"`

Comment: Encoding the whole batch parameter works too... is probably the better way